# Determine possible events, absolute and relative frequencies

Tags: probability, statistics

Grain is planted and after harvesting processed.
From the past is known, that there are average 25 grains per head
provided. By replanting, it was more than 16 grains per head.
These data $x_n$ are in the following table.

[image]

Sort the $x_n$ and determine possible events $E_i$. Determine the absolute and relative frequencies. I would be very thankful if someone could help me with this example and give me some hint or tell me how to even start.

Comment: Notation not really clear (to my anyhow);  You have $x_n = 41$ opposite $n = 1, 5, 7,$ and $13.$ Can you say in English what that means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is the yield (in number of grains per head) from 16 different samples

Sometimes the yield is 25 grains per head (as in the past), sometimes it is more. These are your different events.

$$\begin{array}{|m{cm}|m{cm}|}
\hline \text{Event} &  \text{Grains per head}  &\text{absolute frequency} &\text{relative frequency} \\ \hline \hline \hline E_1& 25& 4 & 0.250 
\\ \hline E_2& 32&2& 0.125\\ \hline E_3 & 36& 6 &0.
375 \\ \hline E_4& 41&4&0.250 \\ \hline 
\text{Totals}& &16&1.000 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$

Comment: Thanks! I should make histogram with these informations, can you tell me should I use absolute frequency or relative frequency for histogram or I should combine both of them?

Comment: If it's a histogram, you usually have a continuous linear horizontal scale (grains per head). You will need to decide how to allocate your "bins" for that. Then you should use frequency density = frequency divided by bin width.